# Meaning of はしゃいじゃって in the attached picture

Tags: meaning

Trying to understand the meaning of はしゃいじゃって

[image: DragonQuestXI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

はしゃいじゃって's base verb is はしゃぐ. The conjugation breaks down like this

> はしゃぐ = base
>
> はしゃいじゃう = base + helper verb しまう
>
> はしゃいじゃって = base + しまう + te-form